# Sending a list of nested objects with files in Postman - c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

My models for a document upload API in c# are as follows:

```
    public class ServiceRequestDocumentResource 
    { 
      [Required] 
      public int? servicerequestId { get; set; } 
      [Required] public string username { get; set; } 
      public List<FileUploadResource> file_list { get; set; } 
    }


  public class FileUploadResource {
    [Required]
    public string file_type { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public IFormFile file { get; set; }
}
```

My API accepts an object of type ServiceRequestDocumentResource .

How do I test this specific API with postman?

I have provided a screenshot of what I have tried sending through postman, and the error:
[Postman request screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gxe6.png)

Comment: how to do you send you parameters ?

Comment: Well it seems like your hitting the api since you are receiving back the validation errors.  Make sure everything that is required is being submitted.  Also make the file not required just to see if the method accepts it.  So your a student at Texas AM!  Good school.  Congrats on getting in.  I used to live in Houston close to there years ago.

Comment: @JSkyS - I am sending all the required params - You can see it in the screenshot i have attached. I get this error only when i try to send the list of files in the format you can see again in screenshot.